# python reading from csv doesn't give the right answer

Tags: python, csv, twitter, sentiment-analysis

This is my first post on this site, so my apologies for any mistakes I make in this post.

I am working on a Twitter Sentiment analysis for a company. I have a csv filled with tweets (just 1 column) and I want to find out if they are talking positively about that company or negatively. 
I found a package that can find the polarity & subjectivity from a sentence. For example, this is my python script were I want to find the results from:

```
from pattern.nl import sentiment
print sentiment('I love this company!')
```

and the result:

```
(0.75, 0.90)
```

At this point, everything works well, but I need to do this for 6000+ tweets, so I thought about reading the csv into the script and do it for each row.

```
import csv
from pattern.nl import sentiment
import sys

f = open('C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\TweetsFromNodeXLOnlyTweets.csv')
try:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        text = row
        print sentiment(text)
finally:
f.close()
```

When I run this, I just get (0.00, 0.00) for all tweets. It seems like the script isn’t able to read it, but when I just print text, I get all tweets as I should. And when I write print sentiment(text), I do get the results I want, but only for that one tweet.
How could I fix this? I am pretty new to Python (started yesterday), but no tutorial or other post on this site could help me with thi!s.

Comment: ^^ @DenStutdent, try what Azad is suggesting. That just might be it.

Comment: @Azad Thanks man! That fixed it. What a silly mistake of me :P

Comment: @Azad, if that's the answer, please post it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According the the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.reader), csv.reader returns lists of strings when iterated, corresponding to the fields in the row. Since your csv is only one column, the list returned will only have one item, so you should access it like this:

`text = row[0]`